# Forms Authentication - loginUrl page executed for each request (Chrome only)

Tags: google-chrome, session, iis, asp-classic, forms-authentication

I think I've pared this down as far as I can. It happens only when using Forms Authentication and only seems to work in IE. So far, I've found that both Chrome and Firefox cause the issue. I have a very simple ASP page that increments a counter (stored in a session variable) on each page load. The page is named `test.asp` and appears in my web root. Here are the contents:

```vb
<%
    ' Write the last value (obviously blank the first time)...
    Response.Write "Last Num: " & Session("Num") &  "<br>"

    ' Increment the counter...
    Session("Num") = Session("Num") + 1

    ' Show the number we just saved...
    Response.Write "This Num: " & Session("Num") & "<br>"

    ' Throw the session ID out there, too, to make sure it's consistent...
    Response.Write "Session ID: " & Session.SessionID
%>

<form method="post" action="test.asp">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

And I've stripped down my `web.config` as much as possible while still reproducing the issue. Here are its contents:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>  
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>         
            <deny users="?" />          
            <allow users="*" />         
        </authorization>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="test.asp" />
        </authentication>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Pretty basic stuff here. I've set `test.asp` as the "login" page and enabled `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`. Things work as expected. All requests are redirected to `test.asp`, as you'd expect. And `test.asp` loads fine, except it for what happens next...

Here's how the page appears in IE (v11), Chrome (v44), and Firefox (v39) when loading initially and after submitting:

**Internet Explorer 11:**

[image]
[image]

**Google Chrome 44:**

[image]
[image]

**Mozilla Firefox 39:**

[image]
[image]

When I click `[Submit]`, I'm obviously expecting the `Last Num` value to be equal to the previous `This Num`. But that only happens in IE. In Chrome, it seems to be doing an extra increment. And in Firefox, it seems to be doing *two*! To make things more confusing, after that initial submission, Firefox properly increments by 1 each time. Chrome, however, continues to double-increment with each submission.

These are default browser installations. No added extensions or special configurations. Cookies are enabled in all three browsers (the default). I can see the `ASPSESSIONID` cookie using the developer tools of each browser. And, as you can see in the screenshots, the `Session ID` is created on page load and stays consistent throughout the session.

If I continue submitting, the results are the same. IE continues to work properly. The other browsers continue to double or triple increment.

Anyone seen this issue before? Or see where I may have gone wrong here? I've tried specifying `cookieless="UseCookies"` in the `<forms>` section of the `web.config` as well.

**Edit 1 - Testing Elsewhere:**

All of my testing to this point has been on my local PC: Windows 7 64-bit with IIS 7.5. Today, I connected to my eventual test server -- a Windows Server 2008 R2 box, also with IIS 7.5 -- and I get the same results there with my test page.

**Edit 2 - loginUrl-related?**

Using a new page, `test2.asp`, with the same content (and given explicit anon access via a `<location>` element in my `web.config`) works fine. So it seems to be `loginUrl` related? Maybe with every page request, it's calling the `loginUrl` page behind the scenes? But again, with some connection to Chrome/Firefox...

**Edit 3 - More Proof:**

I decided to log the value of `This Num` each time the page is executed. Here's what I'm seeing:

**Internet Explorer:**

```
8/4/2015 11:52:07 AM, Num=[1]    Initial page load. One execution.
-----------------------------
8/4/2015 11:52:11 AM, Num=[2]    All future submissions run once.
8/4/2015 11:52:16 AM, Num=[3]
8/4/2015 11:52:20 AM, Num=[4]
```

**Chrome:**

```
8/4/2015 11:34:58 AM, Num=[1]    I get 2 executions on initial page load.     
8/4/2015 11:35:00 AM, Num=[2]    First execution (Num=1) appears in browser.
-----------------------------
8/4/2015 11:35:29 AM, Num=[3]    Every submit causes page to run twice.
8/4/2015 11:35:29 AM, Num=[4]
-----------------------------
8/4/2015 11:35:49 AM, Num=[5]
8/4/2015 11:35:49 AM, Num=[6]
```

**Firefox:**

```
8/4/2015 11:36:25 AM, Num=[1]    I get 3 executions on initial page load.
8/4/2015 11:36:25 AM, Num=[2]    The first execution (Num=1) is the page
8/4/2015 11:36:25 AM, Num=[3]    I see in the browser.
-----------------------------
8/4/2015 11:36:34 AM, Num=[4]    All future submissions run once.
8/4/2015 11:36:43 AM, Num=[5]
8/4/2015 11:36:48 AM, Num=[6]
8/4/2015 11:36:53 AM, Num=[7]
```

**Edit 4 - loginUrl Page Called on Every Request:**

It seems any type of page request is causing `test.asp` to execute behind the scenes, which increments the session variable. And that must be because it's the page identified by `loginUrl` for Forms Auth. Combining the tests I did under edits 2 and 3, I granted anon access to a new test page (`test2.asp`) that doesn't do anything special -- just loads a static page. Here it is:

```
<html><body>I'm test2.asp</body></html>
```

And then I monitored the log file that `test.asp` appends to when it runs. Every time I requested `test2`, I would get a new entry in the log. So every time I made a page request, `test.asp` runs in the background (and increments the session variable). Here's how the log looked after three requests to my `test2` page:

```
8/4/2015 12:20:57 PM, Num=[3]
8/4/2015 12:21:07 PM, Num=[4]
8/4/2015 12:21:14 PM, Num=[5]
```

`test2.asp` doesn't do anything with the session variable (nor logging) but there's the proof. So, for some reason, on Chrome, it runs the `loginUrl` page with each request. I think I can consider that to be proven. Now I just need a solution!

Comment: Are cookies enabled in chrome?

Comment: Yes. Under the cookie settings, `Allow local data to be set (recommended)` is selected and when I click the `[All cookies and site data]` button, I can see cookies from a number of sites including `localhost`.

Comment: Close browser and go back so it's all clear. Then edit the ASP to remove Randomize and the line underneath it out, save it and then hit the submit button. What happens?

Comment: I continue to see a session ID but nothing for `Last Num` or `This Num`, which would make sense since I'm no longer generating numbers. Also, when I first open Chrome, I can go into the developer tools, click the `Resources` tab, and see the ASP session cookie.

Comment: Last Num should still show the contents of the session shouldn't it? You're not altering it after all.

Comment: If there's no value being put into `Session("Num")`, then `Last Num` isn't going to display anything.

Comment: First time you ran it, Session("Num") = Rnd should have populated it yeah? When you remove those two lines, saved it and then submitted the form, it should have displayed the contents shouldn't it?

Comment: I misunderstood what you were suggesting. If I load the page normally, I'll get `This Num`. If I then edit the webpage to comment out those two lines, then hit `[Submit]`, both `Last Num` and `This Num` use the same, new number.

Comment: But how since you're not assigning a new value anywhere? Stupid question, what happens if you delete everything and submit?

Comment: I'm left with just the `[Submit]` button.

Comment: I understand your confusion about the previous test. In my original question, I'm not sure how the new `Last Num` is getting generated with each page submission, either? But somehow it is.

Comment: That's why I asked to remove everything. So the file you are editing is in the root and is called test.asp? Bizarre

Comment: Yes, exactly. No special configuration. Default app pool. Single ASP file. In the root. Default install location (c:\inetpub\wwwroot).

Comment: Have you tried adding a simple counter to the page to see if it's incrementing in a linear fashion?

Comment: @Paul - Just did. When the page first loads, `Last Num = ` (of course), `This Num = 1`. After submit, `Last Num = 2, This Num = 3`. This pattern repeats with each submission. It's like the page is getting executed twice each time.

Comment: @Paul, @pee2pee - Definitely something with the `loginUrl` and/or auth, it seems. If I create an identical page (`test2.asp`) and allow anon access to it, things work fine.

Comment: Could it be that because there's no real authentication happening then it's pushing you back through the test.asp page again, as well as the post in the form?  Try either removing the forms authentication bit or the form method.

Comment: @Paul - I just rewrote the question to make the issue clearer (got rid of the random number stuff). It's definitely related to Forms Auth. I've removed that before and it works fine. The thing is, the `loginUrl` page is supposed to have anon access by default. So I wouldn't think it would be any different than my `test2.asp` example, where I've given the page anon access via `<location>`. Just to test, however, I did add a `<location>` section for `test.asp`, granting it explicit anon access but the issue remains.

Comment: What about putting `?ignore=true` on the end of the `loginUrl` and test for this in the code?

Comment: @Paul - What would you like me to test for there? I did add it, and it does appear in the querystring. If you look at my latest edit (#4), I think I've essentially proven that the `loginUrl` page gets called for every request. Even when I'm running it directly, it gets called behind the scenes (hence the double-increment).

Comment: If you test to see if ignore is true then skip the addition part your code should produce correct results, but, semantically, this isn't resolving the issue; it's simply a workaround.

Comment: Just re-read #4.  I see what you mean.

Comment: Chrome creating own process for each tab. That could be a reason.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With the help of Fiddler, I was able to figure this out.

It seems both Chrome and Firefox make an additional request for your `favicon.ico`, whether or not you've specified that you're using one in your HTLM page. Internet Explorer, on the other hand, doesn't bother.

This was a problem for me for a few reasons:

1. I didn't have one. I'd only just started my site and creating a `favicon.ico` was step 274.
2. I'm using `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`, so requests for icons, like all content, runs through Forms Authentication.
3. If you don't `<link>` to one and specify its location, Chrome and Firefox try to grab one from your web root. Forms Authentication (and my web.config) have my root locked down. The only file being served from my root is my `loginUrl` page.

Each time a request for `favicon.ico` was being made, Forms Authentication was disallowing it and redirecting the request to my `loginUrl` page, consequently causing my `loginUrl` page to be executed *twice* and screwing up my session values. The following Fiddler screenshots show the proof.

Chrome seems to request the icon on every page request:
[image]

Whereas Firefox seems to request it twice initially, for some reason, but then gives up for subsequent requests:

[image]

So, the solution:

1. Create a `favicon.ico` file and place it in your web root.
2. Allow anonymous access to it via a `<location>` element in your root `web.config`.

   ```
   <location path="favicon.ico">
       <system.web>
           <authorization>
               <allow users="?" />
           </authorization> 
       </system.web>
   </location>
   ```

Alternatively (probably the preferred method, since you can designate the name and location):

1. Create a `favicon.ico` file and place it in a public subfolder, like `/img`.
2. `<link>` to it properly within your `loginUrl` page.

   ```
   <link rel="icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
   ```

Comment: Damn you to heck, favicon!

Answer (score 1):

Try `<forms loginUrl="test.asp"  timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />`

Comment: No luck, unfortunately. `Last Num` still continues to be different than the previous `This Num`.